# What's the "Rails Way"? ActionCable channel vs controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

In several tutorials (even one by [David Heinemeier Hansson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0WUjGkDFS0)) you are encouraged to use a method inside the your `x_channel.rb` file to `create` a new message for instance.

It would look something like this (from David's tutorial):

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def speak
    Message.create! content: data['message']
  end
end
```

He then uses the `messages_controller.rb` only to set up a `after_create_commit` for broadcasting the message to all subscribers.

The `speak` method is called by JavaScript.

Now, I was thinking, why use the channel at all for that? I could also just get rid of the `speak` method and instead put a `create` method inside the `messages_controller.rb` with something like this:

```
def create
  Message.create! content: data['message']
end
```

(obviously a little more sophisticated than that but for the sake of demonstration). In the views I would then use a plain old form and an AJAX request to call the `create` method.

Now, I'm wondering which of the two options would be the best or the "Rails Way" of handling this.

Is it "Once you use a channel do everything in there"? Or rather "continue using controllers as much as you can. That's what they were built for"?

Comment: Ever find an answer for this. I asked a question which is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911942/actioncable-why-put-broadcasts-in-a-separate-job-for-forms-why-not-broadcast-f

Comment: Thanks for the response @MCB . Unfortunately not...